# cordova facebookConnectPlugin and publish_actions permission

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have to update our app from using the v1 graph api and sdk methods to v2.X.

I have downloaded the latest facebookConnect plugin found [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

I need to get the user to login to allow our app to post to the users timeline.  Before i have to request publish_scope permission, but this has now changed to publish_actions.

I have tried this code, but apparently you cannot request publish_actions straight away so you have to break it up, and request public_profile first, then publish_actions.  I get this message when trying to do public_profile and publish_actions at the same time

> Cannot pass a publis or manage permission (publish_actions) to a
>   request for read authorization

So my code looks like this, but i dont think i am doing it right?  Do i need the second login call?  Should i be using another method?  Also if the user says "Not now" to the publish_actions permission, there doesnt seem to be a way to handle it, because the success method is called?

Here is some code

```
$(this).find('#imgFacebook').on("tap", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var onError = function(msg, e) {
        console.log(msg + JSON.stringify(e));

        logout();
    };

    var requestPublishPermissions = function(f) {
        console.log('requesting publish permission...');

        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['publish_actions'], function(e) {

            console.log('Permission granted: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

            if (e.authResponse) {

                // user has logged in and allowed permissions!! YAY

            } else {
                alert('There was an error logging you in to facebook, or you did not authorize the app to post on your wall');
            }

        }, function(e) {
            onError('Permission denied: ', e);
        });
    };

    var login = function() {
        console.log('logging in...');

        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile'], function(e) {
            console.log('logged in successfully: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

            requestPublishPermissions(e);
        }, function(e) {
            if (e.errorMessage != 'User cancelled dialog') {
                alert('There was an error logging you in to facebook: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
            }

            onError('login error: ', e);
        });
    };

    var logout = function(success) {
        // check that knowone is logged in
        facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(e) {
            console.log('status is: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

            if (e.authResponse && e.status == 'connected') {
                console.log('logging out...');

                facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function() {
                    console.log('logout successful...');

                    if (success) success();
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log('error logging out: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

                    if (success) success();
                });
            } else {
                // know one logged in
                if (success) success();     
            }
        }, function(e) {
            if (success) success();
        })      
    };

    logout(login);

});
```

Because i do not want to save the users details on the application, i make sure that logout is called first, and then log the user is.

Anyone got any pointers?